# Why is this scatter plot not scatter? Instead it is in a perfect line

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means, scatter-plot

When I try to plot a clustering algorithm following [this](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/plot-k-means-clusters-python) tutorial the following scatter plot is plotted.
I've used my own dataset rather than trying on the provided data.

What could be the possible cause for this issue? **(I've made sure to scale the data.)**

[image]

Sample of dataset: [image]

I've tried to scale and un-scale my data, also tried changing the value of `s`.

Edit: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kqzPRsnKB5lEb91yHxVMDkjHOxr2OJsXFcscw27sOM8/edit?usp=sharing) to sample data.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Thank you for the comment but all of them columns are either int8, int64 or float64 with no null values.

Comment: Please create some short code that reproduces the issue. It is important to show how exactly you normalize the data and call the scatter plot.  Which columns of the dataframe are you plotting?  Maybe you are showing real rating versus estimated rating, and these are rounded (as such, very few possible values). Maybe you have many more rows, and the data are plotted on the same spot? You can try something like seaborn's `sns.stripplot` to add some jitter.